# How to pick 4 non repeat character from a string

Tags: bash, shell

I have write a script that randomly pick 4 character from a string, but the case is the character picked must not be repeated.

For example I have a string like
abcdefgh123
And the function will pick 4 character randomly from the string like 2bfa.

My current solution is working on array index , generate a random number and modulus by the length of array , add it to a stack , pick next random number and compare stack if not in stack , proceed until I got 4 character.

Is there any handy function that allow me to do this easier?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable in with built-in Bash functionality only, no other binaries necessary.

```
pick_unique() {
    declare -r S=${1:?}
    declare -ir N=${2:-4}
    declare s o
    declare -i i j
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#S}; i++)); do
        [[ $s = *${S:i:1}* ]] || s+=${S:i:1}
    done
    ((${#s}>=N)) || return 1
    for ((i = 0; i < N; i++)); do
        j=$((RANDOM % ${#s}))
        o+=${s:j:1} s=${s:0:j}${s:j+1}
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$o"
}
pick_unique 'your_string'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "your_string" | sed 's/./&\n/g' | sort -R | uniq | sed '/^$/d' | head -n 4 | head -c -1 | tr '\r\n' ' ' | tr -d " "
```

Let me explain the steps part by part

1. print your string to STDOUT:

   echo "your_string"
2. separate the whole string to different lines

   sed 's/./&\n/g'
3. sort them randomly and take the unique values with the `uniq` command

   sort -R | uniq
4. remove all the spaces that might have crept before if your string was divided into strings with spaces in between.

   sed '/^$/d'
5. take only the first 4 character. You can change the number based on the requirement.

   head -n 4
6. remove the trailing new line

   head -c -1
7. concatenate all the lines

   tr '\r\n' ' '
8. remove the space between the letters.

   tr -d " "

Comment: @joydeepbhattacharjee uniq only removes consecutive duplicates. `(echo a; echo b; echo a) | uniq` = `echo a; echo b; echo a` That's why you always sort before uniq.